# How to load services in a Docker Stack (Swarm), sequentially one after the other

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have a YML file for Docker Stack which has around 20 different services. There are dependencies such as Config Server, API Gateway and a lot of micro services (SPRING architecture).

*(part of my YML file)*

```
version: "3"

services:
  config-service:
    image: 192.168.0.1:5000/config-service:1.0.7
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    networks:
      - my-gateway-network
    environment:
      - CONFIG_SERVICE_SECURITY_BASIC_ENABLED=false      -
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms256m
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    healthcheck:
       test: curl -s http://localhost:8888
       interval: 15s
       retries: 20
  oauth-service:
    image: 192.168.0.1:5000/oauth-service:1.0.0
    ports:
      - "1116:8080"
    networks:
      - my-gateway-network
    environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Xms128m
    - CONFIG_SERVICE_URL=config-service:8888
    volumes:
    - /opt/authkeys:/opt/authkeys
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    healthcheck:
       test: curl -s http://localhost:1116
       interval: 15s
       retries: 20
```

At the moment when I do

```
docker stack deploy -c <file.yml> myStack
```

It will start all of the services at once, without checking any dependencies. Since its starting them all at once it literally hogs the VM for an amount of minutes, which is not healthy at all.

Is there a way to make it work by loading once service at a time, executed in a particular order and before triggering starting the next service in-line it checks if the container started successfully by executing a healthcheck (simple CURL on an endpoint) to ensure that the spring component is working fine.

Comment: Using Docker version Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Answer (score 0):

I think depends_on option should help

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: compose v3  doesn't support `depends_on`.  Which means swarm doesn't support this.